# How to import json file in stencil component

Tags: stenciljs

I want to import json file with data in StencilJS, like this:

```js
const data = await import('./data.json')

// OR
import data from './data.json'

// OR
import * as data from './data.json'

// OR
const data = require('./data.json')
```

But non of these work.

What I want to achieve is to have a code-splitted, dynamically-loaded json module, or, alternatively, a statically-built json module (not code-splitted, but bundled in at certain paths).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update 2/2021

It's also possible to do this without a plugin, simply by enabling `resolveJsonModule` in `tsconfig.json` (with the added bonus of inferred types).

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

```js
import { version } from '../package.json';
```

(It's important to specify the `.json` extension in this case.)

---

#### Original Answer

You can use [`@rollup/plugin-json`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json) for that, which converts `.json` files to ES6 modules.

```
npm i -D @rollup/plugin-json
```

```js
// stencil.config.ts

import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'

export const config: Config = {
  plugins: [json()],
  // ...
};
```

Then the first three of your import statements should all work, or even named imports
(like `import { version } from './package'`).

Comment: I keep getting `Cannot find module './package' or its corresponding type declarations` error, also added `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in my tsconfig.json file